# php - show the mysql Select query results

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and mysql wanted to bring the results of a select statement.

I tried to use the my code for  the implementation

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv = "content-Type" content = "text/html" charset = "utf-8">
</head>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("hostname","user","password","dbname"); // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "MySQL error : " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT kind,ABS(SUM(money)) AS money FROM Account WHERE userid = 't@t.t' AND DATE_FORMAT(adate,'%Y/%c') ='2014/8'  AND checkio  = 'out'  GROUP BY kind;");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>No</th>
<th>kind</th>
<th>money</th>
</tr>";
$no = 1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $no . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['kind'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['money'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$no++; 
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

No data was not come as a result.
Like this

```
No  kind  money
```

enter on the real mysql Select statement

```
SELECT kind,ABS(SUM(money)) AS money FROM Account WHERE userid = 't@t.t' AND   DATE_FORMAT(adate,'%Y/%c') ='2014/8'  AND checkio  = 'out'  GROUP BY kind;
```

As a result

```
kind money 
 A   1000
 B   2000
 C   1500
```

Come this way ...

Why don't have the output of my code?

Do I need to change in any way?

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead, or pass `MYSQLI_ASSOC` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change any thing in your code simply replace `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` by `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`; you will be fine.

Comment: Although changes. No results have come out.

Comment: check your sql whether it is constructed properly or not.

Comment: i am saying just echo it and see.

Comment: Was the php query encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp) which returns an array with numeric keys. You should either use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp) or `mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.

A revised edition of your code:

```
$no = 1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $no . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['kind'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['money'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $no++; 
}
```

Comment: Although changes. No results have come out.

Comment: Can you please post the result of var_dump($row) inside the while loop?

Comment: How to use var_dump($row)? What's this?

Comment: You should just paste var_dump($row) after `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is the manual of mysqli_fetch_array
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

var_dump function and print_r function will be helpful

var_dump($result) or var_dump($row)